# Creating auto hide popup notification box in Swing

Tags: java, swing, popup

In swing, I want to create a popup notification box which can hide automatically after some seconds. In which ways can this be done ?

It is used on many webpages as pop-up messages like below.

[image]

Comment: JDialog, modal, undecorated, translucent and Swing Timer

Answer (score 1):

I found a library called Jtoaster, Java Toaster is a java utility class for your swing applications that show an animate box coming from the bottom of your screen with a notification message and/or an associated image (like msn online/offline notifications) (from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtoaster/

```
Toaster toasterManager = new Toaster();
toasterManager.showToaster("Hello, this is notification");
```

[image: jtoaster screen]

Answer (score 0):

Jlayer class can help you.

> The JLayer class is a flexible and powerful decorator for Swing components. It enables you to draw on components and respond to component events without modifying the underlying component directly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html